# Printing line by line from alternate files into a third file in c

Tags: c, file

For an assignment I have to input text from 2 files line by line into a 3rd file. So file 1 line 1 would be file 3 line 1 and file 2 line would would be file 3 line 2. I have attempted to this but can not seem to get the lines from each file to alternate. I am only able to get lines from each file separately. Please help with any suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file1, *file2, *file3;
    char line [1000]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */

    // check to make sure that all the file names are entered
    if (argc != 4) {
        perror("Error: ");
        printf("Not enough files were entered!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    file1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");;
    file2 = fopen(argv[2],"r");
    file3 = fopen(argv[3],"w");

    // check whether the file has been opened successfully
    if (file1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        printf("Cannot open file1 %s!\n", argv[1]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    // check whether the file has been opened successfully
    if (file2 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        printf("Cannot open file2 %s!\n", argv[2]);
        exit(0);
    }
    // check whether the file has been opened successfully
    if (file3 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        printf("Cannot open file3 %s!\n", argv[3]);
        exit(0);
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (1) 
    {
            if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file1) != NULL)
            {
                count+=1;
                fprintf(file3, line);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file2) != NULL)
            {
                count++;
                fprintf(file3, line);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
    }

    fclose (file1);
    fclose (file2);
    fclose (file3);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you've been tinkering with your program.  You're close.  Print `line` to `file3`, not `linec`, and it should work.

Comment: P.S. I made my comment *before* you edited your post to get rid of the `if(count % 2 == 0)` condition.  That condition was fine, I'd leave it in.

Comment: yes its working now. But I need to change it so that it continues working even if 1 of the files is done copying lines

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf(FILE *, const char *format, ...)` expects a *format* as the 2nd argument.

Using `fprintf(file3, line);` will invoke undefined behavior (UB) should `line` contain a `'%'` or at least a missing `%` if `"%%"` was encountered.

Use `fputs()`

```
// fprintf(file3, line);
fputs(line, file3);
```

---

Additional concerns for advanced coding:

If the source file contains a null character, using `fgets()` is insufficient as it does not report the length read.  Other approaches include using `fgetc()`, `fread()` or non-standard C `getline()`.

If an input file does not end with a `'\n'`, that rump line may look like a pre-fix to the line read from the other file.

As OP has noted, line length's of about 1000+ are a problem.

Source files line-endings, should they not match the code's understanding of line-ending can cause issues.